# C Grid using pointers and Malloc

Tags: c, pointers, grid, malloc

I am Trying to work through some class examples and have gotten stuck on the following:

The array grid should
have length width with each entry representing a column of
cells. Columns that have some occupied cells should be a
malloc'ed character array of length height.

with the given header:

```
void grid(char **grid, int width, int height)
```

grid is defined in another file as:

```
char **grid;
```

As I have said I have gotten stuck on using malloc, I currently have:

```
int x;
*grid = malloc(width * sizeof(char));

        for(x = 0; x < width; x++){
            grid[x] = malloc(height * sizeof(char));
        }
```

Can any one take a look at give me some pointers on the correct way to accomplish "Columns that have some occupied cells should be a
malloc'ed character array of length height.", As I dont understand how the line:

> grid[x] = malloc(height *
>   sizeof(char));

is equivalent to an array of char's

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, an array is a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) to the first element of the array. So an array is just a memory block, with the array variable pointing onto the first element in this memory block.

[malloc()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malloc) reserves a new memory block of the specified size. To know the size of a type (i.e. number of bytes needed to store one variable of that type), one uses the `sizeof` operator. Hence a character needs `sizeof(char)` bytes, and hence *height* characters need `height * sizeof(char)`.

So with the malloc() call you allocate a memory block to store all the elements of the array, and malloc() returns a pointer onto the first of them.

With C's definition for an array variable (a pointer onto the first element), you can assign the results of `malloc(...)` to your array variable.

Answer (score 7):

`char** grid;` is a pointer to pointer.

```
grid = malloc( width* sizeof( char* ) ) ;  // Statement 1

for( int i=0; i<height; ++i )
{
    grid[i] = malloc( height ) ; // Statement 2
}
```

Understand `char** -> char* -> char`. So first need to reserve for holding addresses amounting to *width*. By *Statement 1*, it is achieved. Now each of these index should point to a memory location holding *height* characters and is achieved by *Statement 2*.

---

Diagramatic representation sounds more clear than description. Hope that helps !
[image: Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
grid = malloc(width * sizeof(char *));
```

You want to allocate space for `width` *pointers to char* - And then you correctly allocate the individual *pointers to `height` chars* in the loop.

Using a typedef makes this more visible:

```
typedef char * charpointer;
charpointer * grid = malloc(width * sizeof(charpointer));
```

Answer (score -1):

1. First you allocate space for array of [width] char pointers. So instead of `*grid = malloc(width * sizeof(char));` which allocates space for [width] chars, you should use `*grid = malloc(width * sizeof(* char));` (the difference is that char is one byte, and char pointer is int (usually 32 bit, but architecture dependent)
2. In your loop, each time you allocate (an array of) [hight] chars and store the pointer to it in one of the pointers that you allocated in (1). so grid[x], actually points to an allocated buffer of chars (which is your array)

hope I made it clear.